# How to find all possible connections between different rows?

Tags: google-bigquery

Our company asked the user to enter various pieces of information including address and license plate in order to get car insurance quotes
We store this information in BigQuery. 
Some users have entered more than one license plate (they might own more than one car) and more than one address at different times. 
Basically the structure could look like this

```
  row   info_1   info_2  
 ----- -------- -------- 
    1   a        y       
    2   a        x       
    3   b        y       
    4   b        z       
    5   c        z       
    6   a        z
```

We want utilize all links between these two pieces of information to have all information from one user in one row
The above table all have connections and should thus be in

Is this possible and what is best practice? 
We have experimented with both STRING_AGG and ARRAY_AGG but have not found the solution yet.

Comment: do you have user_id type of column? which column you use for consolidation?

Comment: We don't have a user_id or anything. Our idea was that after this we would use the GENERATE_UUID() to assign such an id, but for that to work, every user needs to have exactly one row of data if I have understood the problem.
Again I am not completely sure that this is possible in SQL. If you have suggestions for other languages more suitable for achieving this please let me know

Comment: This not about which language more suitable - if you don't have logic in mind of how to achieve your goal - none language will help! If you show us how you think you would do this manually - we might be able to help you, otherwise it is just bag of useless data

Comment: My thought was that we could first ARRAY_AGG all the information grouping by the cookie_id. Then afterwards we would look if any of the columns had the same values but in different rows and then would add the cookie_ids together into the same row. For Alesandro's answer, u1 and u2 share both a and z. Thus we want to assume it is the same human responsible
Does this logic make sense?

Comment: Is this something you still want to be answered?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have an extra column `user_id` and making the input table:

```
  row  user_id  info_1   info_2  
 ----- -------- -------- -------- 
    1    u1       a        y       
    2    u2       a        x       
    3    u1       b        y       
    4    u1       b        z       
    5    u2       c        z       
    6    u2       a        z
```

The following query gives you 2 list of distinct element for `info_1` and `info_1` respectively:

```sql
select
    user_id,
    array_agg(disctinc info_1) as element_in_info_1,
    array_agg(disctinc info_2) as element_in_info_2,
from table
group by 1
```

Test example with input data

```sql
with table as (
  select 'u1' as user_id, 'a' as info_1, 'y' as info_2 union all
  select 'u2' as user_id, 'a' as info_1, 'x' as info_2 union all
  select 'u1' as user_id, 'b' as info_1, 'y' as info_2 union all
  select 'u1' as user_id, 'b' as info_1, 'z' as info_2 union all
  select 'u2' as user_id, 'c' as info_1, 'z' as info_2 union all
  select 'u2' as user_id, 'a' as info_1, 'z' as info_2
)
select
    user_id,
    array_agg(distinct info_1) as element_in_info_1,
    array_agg(distinct info_2) as element_in_info_2
from table
group by 1
```

Result

[image: Query results]

Comment: Thanks for your answer
Unfortunately, we don't have a user_id that we can be 100 percent sure about. This is part of a project trying to create one. We only have different ids set in the cookies but want to work around the possibility that someone has cleared the cookies.
Is this possible?

Comment: You need to have some sort of key that can work as user identifier. As you said you have ids from cookies you may be able to concatenate enough attributes from the cookie to identify the user. However this as side effects. For example, the same person search same of different license place / address pairs on different devices. It will look like different users and if they search on different devices different license plate / address pair it will impossible to trace back to them without an unique identifier.

Comment: Okay
We hope that would could go further than this as we have a lot of information about the users like address, phonenumber, etc.

Comment: Well. If you use a some of those attributes and concatenate them and maybe hash them, that’s your user id and than the solution works.

Comment: That could be a solution for us. Apologies though, I think my last comment was not clear enough. We have this information about many users, but not all of them. Would this change the way you would approach this project?

Comment: Not really. The main question si. Can I create a user identifier from a set of attribute I have? If you can only for a subset of the rows than you can “link” only for those. Yu can play with the method of creating the user id to include more row possible. But if for some you have no information or too few than you cannot associated to a user.

Comment: I will go forward with that then. Do you have suggestions for what datatypes to use? I get issues when using ARRAY_AGG, since I can't do joins later on with arrays

Comment: Because you need to unnest them. `unnest(array_filed) as element` https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays